# HTML/JavaScript UI widgets GUI builder

Tags: javascript, user-interface, widget

I've heard and used some of the libraries like Ext JS, qooXdoo, jQuery UI, dijit. I know there are unofficial attempts to create GUI builders but they are not really great.

Any chance there is a HTML/JavaScript UI widget library with a decent GUI builder?

Answer (score 13):

I'v got a great one: **http://spabuilder.appspot.com**

Answer (score 5):

Ext has (now had) a couple of GUI builders.

[GUI Builder](http://tof2k.com/ext/formbuilder/) by tof2k (he admitted he had no time to work on it anymore when he released it)

Most of these are being replaced/made redundant by [Ext Designer](http://www.sencha.com/products/designer/).

Comment: In fact I think http://www.projectspace.nl/ is updated version, still I was wondering if there is anything else.

Comment: Ha! I thought it was by the webBlocks guys. Well, we'll see what else is out there I guess.

Comment: Here's the thread I found it under, it looks like it was written by them, but when they are cloned like this, it's hard to say:http://extjs.com/forum/showthread.php?t=28133

Comment: Ext JS is nice but seems to be a bit to heavy (also it's free only for Open Source projects). The GUI builder looks impressive but still too far to be considered easy to use. 
Best and easiest GUI builder I've seen so far is the one in Visual C# 2008. I think it's about time to bring some decent GUI builder to web development.
I'm actually considering starting project that would use jQuery + standard html components + chosen jQuery UI components and plugins..

Comment: Oh, yknow, as well as I know ext, you'd think I would have noticed that licensing issue. That's like not even being open source.

Comment: I get "Server not found" when visiting www.webblocks.eu.

Comment: Indeed. I removed it. I looked but couldn't find it anymore.

Answer (score 5):

You may try web based sigma builder. It has more than 30 GUI components supported. 
This builder is pure JavaScript stuff, the only thing which need PHP is to save the generated script in the server side.

By the way, this builder is free and open source under LGPL license.

Answer (score 3):

I can't vote just yet, but I would like to second sigma widgets.  And it does currently support jquery... 
http://www.sigmawidgets.com/products/sigma_visual/VisualJS/index.html

Answer (score 1):

1. [Glimmer](http://visitmix.com/articles/glimmer-a-jquery-interactive-design-tool) is a GUI builder for jQuery. The builder is a closed-source Windows application, but the generated code is all open-source.
2. Isomorphic Software [has a web-based GUI builder](https://www.isomorphic.com/company/pr_56_release.jsp), and is open-source.
3. And then there are ExtJS GUI builders that altCognito mentions.

Comment: Glimmer is not GUI builder, I didn't see any components involved there. I didn't see Isomorphic's SmartClient VisualBuilder in action as it looks like it requires JSP to work. The whole framework seems to be quite powerful but at the same time slow and heavy. Also version with VisualBuilder isn't free.

Comment: In addition, there's Cappuccino, which is a GUI Builder for mac-like web-standards-based applications that run in the browser. They developed a language called Objective-J that duplicates the Mac-native Objective-C language and runs on Javascript:

http://cappuccino.org/learn/

Answer (score 1):

I am search for the same thing. After trying several ones, I find an open source gui builder.
It's very very easy to design gui, you may see it in action. 
http://www.sigmawidgets.com/products/sigma_visual/VisualJS/index.html
It will take several seconds to load it up at the first. 
Unfortunately, it doesn't support jquery.

Answer (score 0):

One of the one I prefer but unfortunately still in beta is www.280atlas.com this is a whole very promising framework "à la Apple". For now the developer beta require to sign up (and this costs 20$)